# Change Directus 7 API url on the Dashboard in Docker

Tags: docker, content-management-system, directus

I am trying to use **Directus 7** in Docker and I have encountered the following problem:

I have not been able to change the API URL in the Dashboard (APP), no matter what I assign to the environment variable `API_ENDPOINT` or `API_URL`. Whenever I open the dashboard it tries to go to the url `http://localhost:7000..../ping`, and since the API is not found there, it fails.

Is there any way to change the API URL in the dashboard in Docker ? I am using the images: `directus/api:latest` and `directus/app:latest`

You can see the example i am using in: https://github.com/directus/docker/blob/master/examples/single-api/docker-compose.yml

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I was able to to exactly what you're describing, by using the `directus/api:2.0.18` and `directus/app:7.0.18` images (instead of `:latest`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the browser-cache or force a reload using shift+f5. had the same prob and it turned out, that the first time a fired up the container I forgot to set the desired endpoint. when reloading the browser did not update the locally cached .js file.

Comment: It can be posted as the comment rather than the Answer.